# Sum syntax for IF condition in Loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Hoping this is an easy answer. Sorry if a dumb question, but I'm trying to figure out the right syntanx for this if statement. I want `THEN` triggered if the entire row sum is the value of the active cell. How can I correct my code?

Code was working until I added the last `OR` assessment `Or Sum(Rng2.EntireRow) = Rng2.Value`

```
For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
    If Rng2.Value = 0 Or Rng2.Value = "" Or Rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Define" Or Sum(Rng2.EntireRow) = Rng2.Value Then
        Rng2.Value = Rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Needs to be `WorksheetFunction.Sum(...`

Comment: @tigeravatar ha awesome, worked perfectly thank you. sorry i'm fairly new to stack overflow is there a way to mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: You can't mark comments as answers.  I'd need to post it as an answer.  This was just kind of a "drive by answer" that was quicker and easier as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code:

```
For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
    If Rng2.Value = 0 Or Rng2.Value = "" Or Rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Define" Or WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng2.EntireRow) = Rng2.Value Then
        Rng2.Value = Rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next
```